# SignalR issue with multiple tab

Tags: angular, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0, signalr-hub

I have written an Application where I am using SignalR. I have search button to get data according to search criteria. (e.g. if you enter customer name and click on search, all the data related to customer name will populate to grid on the screen)

Everything works perfect, in the case I open only one browser. But in the case I open a second instance of the same browser and when I search with TransactionDate on a new browser tab, it replicates the content in the first, even though it should only work on the second.

I am new to SignalR and would really appropriate any help or guidance.

**Angular SignalRService to start connection with api**

```
  this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(this.paymentDraftHubUrl)
    .build();

  this.hubConnection
    .start()
    .then(() => this.hubConnectionStatus = 'Connection started')
    .catch(err => (this.hubConnectionStatus = 'Error while starting connection: ' + err));
}
```

**Hub class in C#**

```
public class PaymentDraftServiceHub : Hub, IPaymentDraftHub
{}
```

**Controller for API** 
using timer to keep calling repository for new data,

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetCsrTranactions")]
public IActionResult GetCsrTranactions([FromQuery] TransactionExceptionDataRequest queryParams)
{
    TimeManager.Dispose();
    var timerManager = new TimeManager(async () =>
    await _paymentDraftHub.Clients.All.SendAsync(SignalRConstants.TransferPaymentDraftServiceData, await _paymentTransactionRepository.GetCsrTranactionsAsync(queryParams)));
    var response = new ResponseMessage { Message = "Accepted", Code = "201" };
    return Ok(response);
}
```

I am new to SignalR and would really appropriate any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understand the documentation which @krish has posted in his answer and prepared my solution to handle different connection and send response to particular connectionId. I also had requirement where i get different parameters with connection so i also have to persist Parameters in to Dictionary.

Hub code

```
public string GetCsrTransactions(TransactionExceptionDataRequest queryParams)
{
   if (Context.Items.TryGetValue(Context.ConnectionId, out _))
   {
     Context.Items.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
     Context.Items.Add(Context.ConnectionId, queryParams);
   }
   else
   {
     Context.Items.Add(Context.ConnectionId, queryParams);
    }

    foreach (var item in Context.Items)
    {
      var isFounded = _disconnectedConnection.TryGetValue((string)item.Key, out _);
      if (!isFounded)
         _disconnectedConnection.Add((string)item.Key, queryParams);
      else
        {
          _disconnectedConnection.Remove((string)item.Key);
          _disconnectedConnection.Add((string)item.Key, queryParams);
         }
    }

    DataManager.Dispose();
    new DataManager(async () =>
    {
      var list = new Dictionary<string, TransactionExceptionDataRequest>(_disconnectedConnection);
      foreach (var item in list)
       {
        await _paymentDraftHub.Clients.Client(item.Key)
                            .SendAsync(SignalRConstants.TransferPaymentDraftServiceData,

        _paymentTransactionRepository.GetCsrTranactionsAsync(item.Value));
         }
        });
      return Context.ConnectionId;
  }

public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
   await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}

public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
{
   Context.Items.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
   await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
}
```

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

**Clients.All** method that you have used in your controller will send messages to all the currently connected clients.

To send the message only to caller you can instead use **Clients.Caller**. SignalR provides much more flexibility when selecting a particular client, You can read more about this in  [SignalR Documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients) .

Comment: As you suggested i got connectionId from client and i am sending response to only particular client with the passed connectionId. but when i open new browser and send a request from that client the previous connection gets disposed. Which means only one conneciton with particular connectionId remains alive.
Is there a way to preserve connections through out all the clients?
**_paymentDraftHub.Clients.Clients.Client(queryParams.ConnectionId).SendAsync(SignalRConstants.TransferPaymentDraftServiceData, await _paymentTransactionRepository.GetCsrTranactionsAsync(queryParams)));**

Comment: You have to create mapping of user and connections, if you want a user to use same connection across browser session, check out this link. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections